# How is $\frac{-2(-1)^n}{n}$ equal to $\frac{2(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Just as the title asks, how is

$\frac{-2(-1)^n}{n}$

equal to

$\frac{2(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$

Comment: You even formatted the question correctly and typed it up using mathjax as well yet you didn't see this?

Comment: @DerekLuna cyan sus

Comment: This questions shows no efforts, doesn't say what and where is OP's doubt and why the OP is not able to prove it. I have to downvote.

Comment: Sorry guys, i'm new to stackexchange. As you se I get really big brainfarts when it comes to math.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\frac{-2(-1)^n}{n}=\frac{(-1)2(-1)^n}{n}=\frac{2(-1)^{n+1}}{n}.$

Comment: i wish i could get 35 points this